# The two pronunciations of 粘

Tags: pronunciation

粘 can be read as either "nian" or "zhan", but in both way it can be translated as "sticky", so what is the difference?
In other words what should I take in mind, when reading a text , in order to understand which pronunciation I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was taught at class, that *zhan* is the reading when 粘 is used as a **verb**, 'to stick, to glue'; the more common reading *nian* covers almost all the other cases, when its used as an **adjective**, 'sticky'. But I think this is not entirely correct.

Here's a [long list](http://zidian.qihaoming.com.cn/zd/zi_16255ec.html) with *compound words*. In most cases the reading is *nian*, in some cases *zhan*. Try to see if you can find a rule.

Interestingly, the Taiwanese Education Ministry's dictionary only lists [nian](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/newDict/dict.sh?cond=%D6%DF&pieceLen=50&fld=1&cat=&ukey=423706689&serial=1&recNo=1&op=f&imgFont=1) as reading.

Answer (score 3):

Originally, you had two separate characters ([zdic](http://www.zdic.net/z/20/js/7C98.htm) [links](http://www.zdic.net/z/29/js/9ECF.htm)):

> 粘 = zhan1 = (v.) to stick
>
> 黏 = nian2 = (adj.) sticky

The usage distinction still remains, but it is now acceptable to use `粘` for either word. Unihan [lists the characters as semantic variants](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E7%B2%98).

Comment: There is an article on this subject [『黏』『粘』『沾』有什麼不同？][1]
The gist is that as noted above 黏 is a stative verb, and 粘 is a verb (intransitive and transitive). It also adds the word 沾 to the mix, but this seems to be a red herring.

There's probably more to be said on this. I'll add if I find more examples/material.

  [1]: http://big5.hwjyw.com/teacher_hua/200910/t20091026_32980.shtml

Answer (score 2):

From a native Chinese perspective:
粘(zhan) = 粘 (nian1) = to glue, to stick = verb.
粘(nian2) = 黏 (nian2) = sticky = adj.

Although 黏 is more used in written, while 粘(nian2) is more oral.